# Verificar se um arquivo existe, dentro de um IF em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Boa tarde,
Gostaria de fazer uma verificação: 
Se um arquivo existe - excluir
Se não existe seguir o fluxo do programa.

Estou usando o Pycharm, está retornando erro de sintaxe,
Mas já coloquei 4 espaços na linha de baixo.
*Obs O resto do código está comentado.*

[image: Print do codigo.]

Segue o código:

```
import os  
import os.path

str(input("Digite Enter Para continuar01"))

if os.path.exists('TM.ext'):
    os.remove("TM.txt")
else:
    print("Arquivo nao existe")
```

Comment: Marcos, o código que vc esta usando é o que esta na foto ? ou o que vc colocou em forma de texto ? o da foto esta cheio de erros de digitação , mas o do texto do post parece bem identado. Qual dos dois se refere ?

Comment: O codigo que vc apresenta esta de uma forma, mas a imagem de outra, na imagem falta os dois pontos na linha do `if`

Comment: @OtávioReisPerkles editei a pergunta, posso ter corrigido a identação, estava mal formatada tb.

Comment: @Sidon Os dois pontos depois do `if` e do `else` foram adicionados [na revisão 2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/348078/revisions), o que pode ter sido um equívoco, pois eles são a causa do erro de sintaxe, e ao colocá-los, descaracterizou a pergunta, pois agora não ocorre mais o erro.

Comment: É, na verdade é o tipo da pergunta que poderia ser evitada se o usuario tivesse cuidade ao fazer a pergunta. :-)

Comment: Meu ultimo comentario virou quase uma recursão. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Note que você não está colocando `:` nas linhas do `if` e do `else` e também se o `path` for uma pasta [`os.path.exists()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) retornará `True` e `os.remove()` lançará um erro.

Você pode testar se o arquivo existe com [`os.path.isfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile), e se existir remover com [`os.remove`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove). Ex.:

```
import os  

if os.path.isfile('TM.ext'):
    os.remove("TM.txt")
```

Ou você pode deletar sem testar se o arquivo existe e captura o [OSError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError) que o módulo lançará. Ex.:

```
import os

try:
    os.remove("TM.txt")
except OSError:
    pass
```

<sup>[Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-348096-6333) com o código funcionando</sup>

---

#### Edit

Para não ficar nada implícito de onde tirei o [OSError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError).

Na [documentação do modulo `os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) é especificado no topo:

> **Note**:
> All functions in this module raise [OSError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError) in the case of invalid or inaccessible file names and paths, or other arguments that have the correct type, but are not accepted by the operating system.

Traduzindo:

> **Nota**:
> Todas as funções deste módulo lançam [OSError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError) no caso de nomes de arquivos ou paths inválidos ou inacessíveis ...

Answer (score 0):

usa este comando é o que eu utilizo nos meus cods:

```
import os.path



if os.path.isfile('arquivo.txt'):
    print("é arquivo")
```

Comment: Com esse codigo, um erro sera gerado, falta os dois pontos na linha do if.Edite sua resposta.

Comment: obrigado. o teclado comeu rsss